# Checking if element contains a string, and nothing but a string - maybe regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have a CMS with a form-module, which generates an awful markup, that makes it absolutely impossible to style. The form objects and elements is nested in an ungodly amount of tables, rows and cells.

I'm working on filtering out all the elements I need through javascript, put them in an array, and create new frontenddeveloper-friendly markup using these elements.

Inputfields, legends and fieldsets is no problem - but I have a problem filtering my labels. My labels are either wrapped like this: `<tr><td>Label</td></tr>` or `<tr><td><b>Label</b></td></tr>` - I need to filter these out, and put them in an array.

Is there a simpler way to check, if my td contains a pure string, and not an input or some other html element, other than using regex?

```
var regex = new RegExp(???);
jQuery("td").each( function() {
    if(jQuery(this).has("b") || regex.test(jQuery(this).text()))
    {
        // Do stuff here
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return all of the td's that either have no children or have a single child which is a bold tag.

```
$('td').filter(function() {
    var children = $(this).children();
    return children.length == 0 
              || (children.length == 1 && children.first().is('b'))
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t9bMG/

If you want to only return elements that actually have text you can use this:

```
$('td').filter(function() {
    var t = $(this), children = t.children();
    return t.text().length > 0 
               && (children.length == 0 
                    || (children.length == 1 && children.first().is('b')))
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t9bMG/1/

Comment: I also have a lot of td's with no children and no strings, so I still need to make sure that the td actually contains a string.

Comment: This works as well, and is an acceptable answer too, but the regex-way is more simple I think. Thanks though! :)

Comment: Np, your question did explicitly state 'other than using regex' ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this regex

`var regex = new RegExp('^[^<]*$')`.

This would match if there is no opening html tag anywhere in the `td` text. If you don't want to match empty strings then use `+` instead of `*`.

**Explanation**

```
"^" +       // Assert position at the beginning of the string
"[^<]" +    // Match any character that is NOT a “<”
   "*" +       // Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible
"$"         // Assert position at the end of the string
```

Comment: I'll try this approach - it seems more simple, and was just what I was looking for.